# How can I set max and min dynamically in <v-slider> in vue 2.0 when i am extracting max and min from a table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-slider

Code:Also help me how can i take steps of 5 here

```
<v-slider v-model="list1" :min="1" :max="1000">
                            </v-slider>
    data () {
            return {"list1": [0,1] //list 1 will have all the range of data selected.
    }
    }

    created()
    {
    //method call to extract the table data where i calculate max and min in table too
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<v-slider v-model="list1" :min="minValue" :max="maxValue">
                            </v-slider>
    data () {
            return {
             list1: [0,1], //list 1 will have all the range of data selected.
             minValue: 1,
             maxValue: 1000
          }
    }

    created()
    {
      //method call to extract the table data where i calculate max and min in table too
      this.minValue = <calculated minimum value>
      this.maxValue = <calculated maximum value>
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work!

vue-slider-component.umd.min.js?4971:6 [VueSlider error]: The prop "interval" is invalid, "(max - min)" cannot be divisible by "interval"

Comment: I think since my v-model is for list1, hence it's getting the slider to contain these values only. Sorry, a newbie so not much idea

Comment: Just check if values in the list1 are in range of minValue and maxValue

Answer (score -1):

When `dynamically` setting the `max`, you should ensure that the number of decimal places in the max matches the `interval`. For example:

```
{min: 0, max: 100.5, interval: 0.1}

or 

{min: 0, max: 100.55, interval: 0.01}
```

This way, it's possible to get to the `max` from the `min` using the interval.